# Unexpected results in Firebug

Tags: javascript, floating-point, sum, ieee-754, exponential

Unexpected results in Firebug console. Why in this operation: 1.7E16+2 the last number is 2 and in 1.7E16+3 operation the last number is 4 :D This is a JavaScript Bug?

[Firebug unexpected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7sq7.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is not unexpected. This is standard floating point behavior.

You really should read '[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)'.

If that material is too complicated, and it most definitely is, http://floating-point-gui.de is a very concise alternative.